# List of screen resolutions doesn't go up to my monitor's native resolution

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, resolution

I recently installed Windows 7 on my desktop computer and found that even after going to *Display* settings and setting it to the highest setting that there's still black space between the edge of the display and the edge of the monitor. Also, that resolution isn't as high as my monitor's native resolution (it's telling me I can go as high as 1400 x 1050, and I think mine goes as high as something close to 1920 x 1280).

I believe that my monitor is an [ASUS ML228](http://www.asus.com/Monitors_Projectors/ML228H/).

When I try to detect my monitor/graphics card with [DxDiag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DxDiag) it tells me that they are named "Standard VGA Graphics Adapter" and "Generic PnP Monitor".

Comment: You need to update your display drivers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to install the correct graphics driver for your card. Find out what type of video card it is, then visit the manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the drivers for the graphics card to me.

Start by finding out exactly what type of graphics card you've got and then go to the manufacturer's web site to get the latest Windows 7 drivers, install them and reboot.